# In app billing: isn't it possible to undo purchase?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I  implemented android in app billing, uploaded it in developer console for alpha tests, created an item (one time product for premium version) and tested on my device. Everything worked, but I wanted to test a second time with same device - isn't it possible to undo purchase?

What I tried:

- I canceled the purchased item in developer console --> nothing happened on my device, BillingClient.getPurchaseList still returned my premium purchase
- I cleared cache with ad command "adb shell pm clear com.android.vending" --> and now it's getting strange:

First, I thought it works and BillingClient.queryPurchases().getPurchaseList didn't return any purchase and my app behaviour changed correctly to basic version. But if I try to buy the item one more time to test the purchase flow again, it says "item already owned". Isn't there any possibility testing it again??

Another strange thing I absolutely don't understand: I didn't do anything, openend my app a few hours later again and it is marked as premium again. What does that mean? Is in a problem in test account or can that also happen in real (canceled) purchases??

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to allow an item to be purchased multiple times (i.e in-game currency), you should consume it before buying it again, otherwise the IAB library will return the `"Item already owned"` error.

To reset a purchase you can use `BillingClient#consumeAsync(String purchaseToken)`.

To get the `purchaseToken` of a purchase, use `BillingClient#queryPurchaseHistoryAsync`, this will return the list of current purchases.

If you want to consume all purchases for debugging purposes, you can just use the following code:

```
client.queryPurchaseHistoryAsync(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP, new PurchaseHistoryResponseListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPurchaseHistoryResponse(int responseCode, List<Purchase> purchasesList) {
                        if (purchasesList != null && !purchasesList.isEmpty()) {
                            for (Purchase purchase : purchasesList) {
                                client.consumeAsync(purchase.getPurchaseToken(), new ConsumeResponseListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onConsumeResponse(int responseCode, String purchaseToken) {
                                        if (responseCode == BillingResponse.OK) {
                                          //Item consumed, you may repurchase it now
                                        } else {
                                            // Error, item not consumed. See responseCode for more info
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
```

Trying to clear cache won't fix the problem because as soon as the IAP library resyncs with GPlay, it will remember the purchases associated with the account of the current user.

Comment: Samuel, thanks for your answer. As described in the official documentation "BillingClient.queryPurchases()" should only return active purchases, but in my example the item in canceled... What happens in real life, if a user cancels a purchase? Is is stil returned as an active item, if I use queryPurchases checking if a user can use premium functions?

Comment: client.consumeAsync solved my problem. The item got "consumed" - although it is a managed product and I could buy it again and test the purchase workflow. Thanks for your help. Maybe someone can answer the question why "BillingClient.queryPurchases()" return canceled items. I'm still confused about it...